# Interesting data from stool/poop

Tags: digestion, quantified-self, stools, dna, flora

I'm interested in getting personal health data from unusual sources. What are some surprising things you can learn from your stool/fecal material, e.g. regarding:

1. Gut flora
2. Digestive health
3. Metabolic health [from break down waste products]
4. Diet
5. From trace amounts of DNA

Yes, obviously stool may not be as informative as other health related tests, e.g. blood tests, so would  not be the most direct way to assess certain things. However, it is still a non-invasive and potentially useful additional source of data about your own body, so please only provide serious answers.

Comment: There are a few new tests designed to detect colon cancer from a stool sample. Whether or not they are used frequently or are in any guidelines I don't know. The CDC lists 3 different methods for stool testing here: http://www.cdc.gov/cancer/colorectal/basic_info/screening/tests.htm